# Problem :simple query takes too long to complete (over 7 minutes)

Tags: postgresql-performance, pgadmin-4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_question_3_3()
RETURNS TABLE(name character varying, surname character varying, person_t person_type)
AS
$$
DECLARE
       pt person_type;
BEGIN
     RETURN QUERY
     SELECT DISTINCT pr.name, pr.surname, pr.person_t
     FROM "Person" pr
     CROSS JOIN "Professor" prof 
     CROSS JOIN "LabTeacher" lt 
     CROSS JOIN "Student" st;
           IF pr.amka = prof.amka THEN
                pt = 'Professor';
           ELSIF pr.amka = lt.amka THEN
                pt = 'LabTeacher';
           ELSE
                pt = 'Student';
           END IF;
           pt = pr.person_t;
END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT*FROM fn_question_3_3()
```

So I'm trying to make a simple query here where i check for the amka of the person and if it is the same as one of the other tables then it updates the person_t column and it returns name, surname, and person_t.

The problem is that the query `SELECT * FROM fn_wuestion_3_3()` takes over 10 minutes to complete and that shouldn't be the case for a query like that. Any help would be appreciated since I'm very new to databases and postgresql/pgadmin4.

table : "Person" has 4820 rows
table : "Professor" has 123 rows
table : "LabTeacher" has 77 rows
table : "Student" has 3194 rows

Index definitions are pr for "Person", prof for "Professor", st for "Student" and lt for "LabTeacher" tables respectively.

Comment: I'm very new to stackexchange (just became a member) so I have some problems in showcasing, I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I honestly can't make head or tail of what you want. Do you want to just select data, or do you want to modify the table? Why does your query have three cross joins and no filters? In fact, why do you have any joins at all if all you want is the data from `Person`?

Comment: Update: the query has still been running for 50 minutes now.

Comment: What I want to do is I'm checking the amkas and if i find amka on person to be equal with an amka from another table then, since the value person_t is null in the table im updating it with the type. And then I want to show the name that have a person type and are not just random in the person table and also based on the amka to show what type of person they are. I am sorry if my code is bad, i just started working on a uni project since 3 days and I have no experience prior to that.

Comment: I want to modify the table and then show the new data, because since person_t column is  NULL, i am trying to add values to that column using the amkas

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: the IF THEN ELSE seems misplaced. plus pt is assigned and then reassigned?  is it intended to be a join condition?  as others are saying, cross-joins are really bad ideas, much less 3 cross joins in a single query (which joins the rows of each of the 4 tables together in every possible combination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you include table "Student" in the query? It is not used anywhere except the `from`. Do not include tables you are not using.

Do not do `cross join` - it is a very broad join with very limited cases of usability. In fact, the only usage of 'cross join' is on pages of textbook. Never in real life.

> And then I want to show the name that have a person type

So do just that:

```
select
    pr.name,
    pr.surname,
    (case
        when prof.amka is not null then "Professor"
        when lt.amka is not null then "LabTeacher"
        else "Student"
    end) as person_t
from "Person" pr
left join "Professor" prof on pr.amka = prof.amka
left join "LabTeacher" lt on pr.amka = lt.amka
```

Comment: Thank you the problem has now been resolved. Thank you also for the broad advice, @White Owl